# Examples of web based Overweight/Oversize load permit routing on County Roads

Tags: web-service, transportation

Does anyone know of any US counties that have set up a web based [overweight/oversize load permit routing system](http://onlinepubs.trb.org/onlinepubs/archive/NotesDocs/20-07%28254%29_OS-OWPermit.pdf), preferably one that leverages GIS?

I know many state DOT's are doing this, but I don't see any that integrate with county maintained roads.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Kirk, 
I actually wrote the old Oklahoma Size & Weights Permits system (the one they are using until the new Cambridge System takes over in August) and as part of the design did a survey of existing state permitting systems.  Because of the vast disparity between municipalities and their systems/infrastructure, every state I know of has language that requires the trucking company to contact any city/county whose roads they will be transporting on to get approval prior to shipping.

Obviously some companies do not do this but the states are effectively left with this as the only solution as they neither have authority or responsibility for municipally owned roads.  My guess is that even IF the states' permit systems could be designed to handle non-state roads (and many of them can) for legal reasons they are unlikely to do so.

As for a county querying a permit system, I don't know of any that do but there is no technical reason why they couldn't.  It might take some time/money to develop a way to give the county access but it certainly could be done and it would definitely be helpful for enforcement.

Comment: Great to hear from you Bobby.  I read through the [press release](http://www.camsys.com/pressreleases/pr_nov09_OklDOT.htm) linked to by Brad.  I don't see any mention of open standards.  Seems like there should be a requirement for standards that would allow counties to implement systems that at least query the state system. Do you know if there were any such requirements?

Comment: There is not and in fact there is very little standardized between the states to base a "standard" on.  The closest thing that Oklahoma has is the federal highway standards but those only apply to federally regulated routes.  That said, technically speaking, it shouldn't be that hard to give county access if there was enough pressure to do so.  Maybe you could try starting with an open records request.

Answer (score 0):

Not Positive. I know Oklahoma has a system. [Oklahoma permit system story](http://www.camsys.com/pressreleases/pr_nov09_OklDOT.htm)
If you need I can put you in touch with someone close to this system.
They may be able to answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks Brad.  It looks to me like they're just handling the part of the route that falls on state roads.  For things like oil drilling equipment, they usually end up going down county and local roads too.  What I'd really like to know is if a county roads department can query the state system to see route permits granted by the state that start or end within a particular county.

Comment: I'll ask, He is on the GIS-T forum. Actually saying that makes me think that would be a good place to ask your question also.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Texas DOT will be implementing a Oversize load GIS webmap/permit application system called [TxPros](http://www.dot.state.tx.us/business/motor_carrier/overweight_permit/txpros.htm) sometime in May 2011.

Comment: Thanks artwork, they've told me they have no current plans to do permit routing on county roads.  I'd think there must be a county somewhere in the US (or better yet, Texas) that does there own permit routing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [New York's](https://www.dot.ny.gov/osowscreen) example. I have been part of market scans, research, and implementation process of online commercial vehicle permitting systems.